# Handle kafka offsets while parallelly processing messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am creating a service that polls messages from Kafka topics and hands over each message received during the poll interval to a worker thread from the thread pool. The worker thread processes the message by talking to another service.

How should I handle committing Kafka offsets for this case? If I choose to wait for all the threads to complete, the processing speed decreases. Also once a message reaches a worker thread, it is guaranteed that either the message processing completes successfully or the message is added to a dead letter topic to be seen later if some error occurs during message processing provided that the host on which the service is running doesn't go down. So I may commit the offsets as soon as I have submitted the messages to the thread pool but then I run the risk of losing messages for host crashes. How should I prevent losing messages here or should I use some other strategy for committing/ maintaining offsets.

Comment: You could use an asynchronous callback from the worker thread once complete and commit the offsets, but there's no guarantee of ordering once you're handing messages off to them

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes for every call back I need to check if all the previous offsets have been committed or not which again is not straight forward.